# git.kernel.org mirror for Linux kernel

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I'm finding that `git.kernel.org` is slow, are there any mirrors available?

I am specifically looking for tag `v2.6.35.3` with git commit id `6d23f5084c975be637f7d748db82116bf84d3872`.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck with the kernel mailing list. Must be a dev out there who's got that tree.

Comment: Why the down + close votes, please?

Comment: Google's mirror: https://opensource.googleblog.com/2012/04/worldwide-mirrors-of-gitkernelorg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular commit available over numerous source on the Internet:

http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6d23f5084c975be637f7d748db82116bf84d3872

As for an example you can safely clone it [from other Linux repositories on GitHub.](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/samsung-kernel-crespo/commit/6d23f5084c975be637f7d748db82116bf84d3872)

Comment: It worked, thanks. I actually had been looking for another repository with that commit id on goole, without any luck.